# A few questions on an application of the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, winding-number

I have got the following closed curve $\gamma$

[image]

and I am supposed to calculate
\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma\frac{\cos(z)}{z^3(z^2 +1)}dz
\end{equation}

with the help of the residue theorem.
Now, I've got a few questions

1. $0$, i and -i are the isolated singularities of our given function. As far as I understand it, the winding number of $0$ is $-2$, the winding number of $-$i is $-1$ and the winding number of i is $0$. Is this correct?
2. How can I determine the residue in this case? For a start, I tried finding the Laurent expansion for $z_0=0$, but I have no idea how to rearrange the equation further. I only got as far as
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{\cos(z)}{z^3(z^2 +1)}=\frac{1}{z^2+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{z^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}.
   \end{equation}
   Could someone give me a hint on how to find the Laurent expansion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @José has given you a good answer. If you don't like using "rules" to calculate the residue, but want to see the relevant bit of the Laurent Series , just expand $(1+z^2)^{-1}$ as a GP as usual. You'll get the same residue (!).

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusions about the winding numbers and singularities are correct.

At $z=0$, $\cos(z)=1-\frac12z^2++O\!\left(z^4\right)$ and $\frac1{1+z^2}=1-z^2+O\!\left(z^4\right)$. Thus,
$$
\frac{\cos(z)}{z^3(1+z^2)}=\frac1{z^3}-\frac32\frac1z+O(z)
$$
At $z=\omega$, where $\omega^2+1=0$, the residue is
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to\omega}(z-\omega)\frac{\cos(z)}{z^3(z^2+1)}
&=\frac{\cos(\omega)}{\omega^3}\lim_{z\to\omega}\frac{z-\omega}{z^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\cos(\omega)}{\omega^3}\frac1{2\omega}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\cosh(1)}2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

1. You are right.
2. Let $f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}$. Then\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{z^3(z^2+1)}\right)&=\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{f(z)}{z^3}\right)\\&=\frac{f''(0)}{2!}\\&=-\frac32.\end{align}